# How to Render water Particles in separate render passes

Tags: rendering, particles, render-passes

I have a very large fluid simulation and I would like to render the particles on different render passes. I am running out of Vram, I am rendering with a RTX 3090 but I guess I found its cap. I can seem to find how to render each particle system on separate passes. I think if I can render the spray, foam, and bubbles I can build even more complex scenes. any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Bump down from OptiX to CUDA to utilize shared memory pool.  Slower rendering, but you might avoid this problem altogether.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I will give it a try. I would still love to find a way to render separate passes for compositing in the future.